# Выдает ошибку при приеме параметра

Tags: php

Подскажите, в чем здесь ошибка? Просто я в  php не очень разбираюсь...

```
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {$type = $_POST['type']; }
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {$id = $_POST['id']; }
}
```

Запрос вида domen.com/file.php?type=action?id=number

Ошибка типа 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in `if (isset($_POST['type'])) {`

Comment: ошибка может быть не в этих строках... где пропущена фигурная скобка...

Comment: А зачем второй раз проверять установленность `$_POST['type']`?

Answer (score 2):

В этом коде нет ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

1. "domen.com/file.php?type=action?id=number" - у Вас тут GET-запрос
2. если делаете GET-запрос, то type=action&id=number (у Вас там дважды "?")
3. скорее всего, ошибка выше данного выражения - покажите весь код